# expected identifier or '(' in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am trying to follow one Apple's Core Data Tutorial for iOS but can't get past this error.

I have tried to work it out from reading all the questions on here but getting nowhere -

Any ideas?

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

UINavigationController *navigationController;

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UINavigationController *navigationController;
 // expected identifier or '(' on the line above

@end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Better solution -- change your text preferences to bind ctrl-return to an actual newline.

I wrote a [blog post with screenshots](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2012/12/23/xcode-sometimes-a-return-is-not-a-return-emacs-brain-damage/).

---

What @jlehr said, but with steps.

1. go to the end of the line that declares `navigationController`
2. hit <kbd>ctrl-a</kbd>

If the cursor goes to the beginning of the line declaring `window`, then the newline at the of that line is bogus.

Quick fix; with cursor at the beginning of the line declaring `window`, hit the <kbd>down-arrow</kbd>, then <kbd>delete</kbd>, then <kbd>return</kbd>.

Happens to me all the time because I have emacs deeply ingrained and, thus, hit <kbd>ctrl-return</kbd> which inserts the wrong type of newline, causing the compiler to barf.   File a bug, too, please, it'll be marked as a dupe but a dupe indicates the frequency with which this frustrates users.

Comment: +1. Much as I love my emacs key-bindings, I run afoul of the same problem from time to time. Nice little technique for finding and fixing in place!

Comment: Basically what I said that got downvoted and deleted, sometimes people are too slow understanding.

Comment: It isn't from copy/paste and it had nothing to do with the @end.  Your answer was vaguely correct and specifically incorrect.  Didn't warrant a down vote, IMO, that wasn't me.

Answer (score 2):

Remove this statement or change the variable name:

```
UINavigationController *navigationController;
```

and try again.

You have same variable name in same class twice. one as property and one as global.

Edit:

Or your intension was to use as ivar, so you should use as :

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>{
    UINavigationController *navigationController;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UINavigationController *navigationController;

@end
```

Comment: "You have same variable name in same class twice. one as property and one as global." The static scope rule is applied, there isn't any conflict.Also, a global variable isn't "in a class".

Comment: Yes, I agree, but it is bad programming practice, isn't it? Even Global and same name, 2 bad practices in above code.

Comment: In the documentation is says: Add the Navigation Controller Property
You need to add a property for the navigation controller.
>> In the application delegate’s header file (LocationsAppDelegate.h), add an instance variable:

￼￼￼    UINavigationController *navigationController;

￼>> Add the property declaration:

￼￼￼    @property (nonatomic, retain) UINavigationController *navigationController;

What have I done wrong?

Comment: So you got the answer already, see my edit code, try this one.. the documentation's replica is like that only.

Comment: Even if I remove UINavigationController *navigationController; it still has the error. Sorry - new to all this and that is why I am trying to follow Apple's docs.

Comment: What are they? And can you try by `strong` only, however this doesnt have to do with this error.

Comment: They are the same - expected identifier or '(' Changing retain to strong does not do anything. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Can we use TeamViewer so that I can use your application and check it online?

Comment: Well that would be great but I am in Ethiopia and connection is dialup  - very slow. I am not sure it would work.

Comment: I'll try and download it and see

Comment: have a try, i would have asked to mail you code, but I don't have mac with me, am using PC :(

Comment: Thanks - it is going to take an age to download. Thanks anyway. I'll try and figure it out.

Comment: Or you can mail me tomorw night, so that I can check it on Monday in my office. :p   I hope before it you will defintely sort out this problem.

Comment: One last try. delete the project and create a new project.

Comment: Thanks again. I'll give it a go and get back to you if I am still stuck. All I have done is followed http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/iPhoneCoreData01.pdf and I was up to page 18.

Answer (score 2):

The code you posted compiles cleanly on my machine, so in all likelihood the version in your Xcode project contains a stray, non-printing character, probably on the line where you declare the `window` property. As a quick experiment, try commenting out that line to see if that's where the problem is.

Once you've isolated the line that contains the problematic character, leave it commented out and retype the text on a new line. Once you've got that working you can delete the commented code.

Comment: Incredible. Just went back to this and deleted the line return between  the two property lines, pressed return and error has gone. I can't thank everyone enough for all trying to get to the bottom of this. A rouge line end it seems.

I am intrigued by the comment "You have same variable name in same class twice. one as property and one as global." I am not sure that is true. I am new to all this but is this comment correct?

Once again thanks - much appreciated.