# Header Search Path Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode6, cocoapods

I am trying to run a project having some header files but these header files are having path of the actual location of header file like "../../../FMRuntimeHelpers/Classes/FMRuntimeHelpers.h".

Now compiler is not considering this path ( ../../../FMRuntimeHelpers/Classes/FMRuntimeHelpers.h) to locate the actual header file and the its content like @interface etc. While its considering this as Objective C code and generating error: "Expected Identifier or '('".

Please suggest. What I need to do to resolve it? How can be define this relative path? I am having thousand of files in this manner so this would be taking considerable amount of time to replace these files with the original files.

[image]

Comment: See if this answer helps .. .  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14003494/expected-identifier-or-in-ios

Comment: That file is not a valid .h file, you can't just put a path there, you need to either add #import or #include before the path... Also, it seems like that path is to the file itself, why would you need to include a file from itself?

Comment: If I navigate to this path(../../../FMRuntimeHelpers/Classes/FMRuntimeHelpers.h) in finder, I found the FMRuntimeHelpers.h having the valid header content. I do not understand why the path of valid header file is referenced in this way. I am having thousand of files in this manner so could not even replaced all with the original header.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Method 1 :

- Select the "Source Tree" tab in Xcode's preference. A path added here will be a system-level path and available to be included for all projects.
- Set HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS parameter in build settings on project info. I added "${SRCROOT}" here without recursion. This setting works well for most projects.

method 2 :

Xcode uses Clang which has GCC compatible command set. [GCC has an option -Idir](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html) which adds system header searching paths. And this option is accessible via HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS in Xcode project build setting.

However, path string added to this setting should not contain any whitespace characters because the option will be passed to shell command as is.

But, some OS X users (like me) may put their projects on path including whitespace which should be escaped. You can escape it like /Users/my/work/a\ project\ with\ space if you input it manually. You also can escape them with quotes to use environment variable like "${SRCROOT}".

Or just use . to indicate current directory. I saw this trick on Webkit's source code, but I am not sure that current directory will be set to project directory when building it.

The ${SRCROOT} is predefined value by Xcode. This means source directory. You can find more values in [Reference document](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can manually add this header search via Target->Build Settings->Header Search Paths(there you can add relative path like ../../) and just use header file in your project.

Comment: Added header "../../" in "Header Serch Paths". Clean and build the project, still facing the same error. Tried with "../../../" also.

Answer (score 0):

if your Xocde version is 6.1，you need to set its preferences like pic,and make xcode build as your target setting 
[image]